# Can you use instances as part of a skin?

Tags: armature

I made this limboish guy to learn how to create armatures.

[image]

I thought I would use instances for the hands, so that when I make changes to the hand mesh, both would update.

[image]

After which I learned that you cannot use modifiers with instances. Since being deformed by an armature is a modifier, this seems to mean that instances cannot be part of a skin.

**Is there a way to use instances as part of the skin of an armature?**

*(One way to overcome this would be to "make duplicates real" and then apply the modifier. That would defeat the point though, as changes would no longer be reflected in both hands.)*

Comment: Why you need to apply the modifier to the istances in this case?

Comment: @Carlo How can I get the hand instances to move when I pose the hand bones, unless they have the Armature modifier?

Comment: By **adding** to your object an Armature modifier, as you did. But I'm asking why you would like to **apply** it, which is the thing that gives you problems.

Comment: @Carlo Ah I shouldn't have said "apply", I meant just adding a modifier. You can't add modifiers to instances, so I don't know how to use an instance with an Armature.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand properly what you are saying. You do can add modifiers to instances. Why you say you don't? Can you make an example?